# Unable to give provider name by using SMS Api Extension

Tags: civisms

1. I downloaded SMS Api Extension (v1.3) in civicrm version 4.5.0.
2. After that i am unable to give Provider name.(As there is no option to give provider name)
3. Then i went to https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.smsapi .... There in commits "fixed provider name fixed section". It showing two changing files which was missing in last released SMS Api version 1.3.
   4.So i created CRM/Smsapi/CivirulesAction.mgd.php and CRM/Smsapi/CivirulesAction.php inside org.civicoop.smsapi (which is the extension diretory name)

When i opened --> Settings - SMS Provider --> Still creating of provider name option is not coming.

Please suggest.

Comment: I am hoping one of developer should fixed the sms problem in civicrm as i knew there is very less respond in case of civisms.

Answer (score 1):

Sandeep are you looking to setup SMS in CiviCRM?

We successfully setup SMS in CiviCRM 4.6.8 using Twillio - https://www.twilio.com/

We followed the exact steps here - http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Setting+up+a+SMS+Provider+for+CiviSMS

and use From=614111111111 where 61 is the country code (Australia in our case).

Comment: Thanks Sohal, I knew the setup for Twillio and MysmsMantra. I want to use some different sms provider to setup SMS in CiviCRM.